# iOS to Parse.com - SaveInBackground Object ID is null

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am struggling to find why I am getting a null value when using SaveInBackgroundWithBlock to Parse.com. I am sure I am missing something, have tried both if (!error) and if(succeeded) with same result which is that the object is created but eventID (the objectID) is null... Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

```
[event saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        [CommonHelper hideBusyView];
                        EventObj *obj = [[EventObj alloc] init];
                        obj.eventID = event.objectId;
                        obj.eventName = strNameEvent;
                        obj.eventDateTime = self.dateEvent;
                        obj.eventAddress  = strAddress;


                        NSLog(@"EventID: %@",self.eventObj.eventID);

                        PreviewInvite *invitepreview =[[PreviewInvite alloc] init];
                        invitepreview.eventObj = self.eventObj;

                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:invitepreview animated:YES];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
                        [CommonHelper showAlert:errorString];
                        [CommonHelper hideBusyView];

                    }
                }]
```

Comment: 1. where are you declaring or assigning the value to eventObj.eventID?
2. You shouldn't do UI stuff (like pushViewController) in a background thread

Comment: Where are you setting self.eventObj?

Comment: Oh, just realized TooManyEduardos said the same thing. But yeah... is that what's null?

Comment: Sorry, still learning but saveInBackgroundWithBlock is responsible for saving the object to Parse.com. the eventObj.eventID is what is null but I was thinking that Parse was giving me event.ObjectId after the save.

Comment: @StevenCarlton Yeah, you should be able to get `event.objectId` after the save. Is that null too?

Comment: Alrighty event.objectId is NOT null. So why is self.eventObj.eventID null?

Comment: What *is* self.eventObj.eventID? How do you declare it and initialize it? There's no mention of that in your code above... So you clearly didn't set it to the objectID returned after the save...

Comment: Steve, i think you are getting mixed up with the naming of the variables. Your self.xxx object is completely separate from the coding with the return block. If you had use something akin to:
    [self.eventObj saveInBackgroundWithBlock   ... etc

then it would be a differing story.

Comment: @drew.. I think you are right, I misunderstood 'self' so I was simply looking for the wrong variable. Should have been looking for obj.eventID which returns the expected result.

    NSLog(@"EventID: %@",obj.eventID);

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott thank you for your help as well!